# Apache cache control on Django MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, django

I've a Django application with a directory /media/ for all static files. (css, images, js)

I want to speed up the serving of these files with Apache cache control.

How can I setup cache control for ALL that directory?

**UPDATE**

I've put this in my **/etc/apache2/site-available/mysite.com**

```
 <Directory "/srv/www/mysite.com/myproject/media/">
 Options -Indexes
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=108000, public"
 </Directory>
```

But I get this when I try to load my site with Firefox:

[image]

What is in Request Heards **Cache-Control: max-age=0** ?
It is not wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ExpiresDefault`  inside `<Directory "/path/to/media">` to set cache control to all files within this directory. See [mod_expires documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html)